# can't complete Arch Linux installation guide

Tags: archlinux

I'm following arch linux installation guide ([this one](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide)) step by step, but in some point I can't continue, in this part:

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Region/City /etc/localtime
```

It can't be done because the file doesn't exist

Any idea?

Comment: You should provide the full command AND the output generated exactly, copied from the console.

Comment: it's the command exactly as I put in the console, and localtime doesn't exist. But as soon as I can, I'll put the exact output here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you are talking about is not meant *literally*.

*Region* should be replaced with your region.
*City* should be replaced with the name of a big city inside your region.

Arch Linux does not have a file for every city in the world, but has files for the larger cities. So choose a large city which is close to you.

I live in Vienna, so my command looks like this:

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Vienna /etc/localtime
```

While you write the command into the shell, you can use tab-completion to see if the region/city you want to choose exists as an Arch-Linux-file/directory.

Answer (score 1):

the command you are using might be old.  I just did an arch install and when using your command I received cannot access /etc/localtime no such file for directory.

However, in the /etc/local* I found /etc/locale.gen and it set my timezone when doing the date command to see

so try for example
`ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Canada/Eastern /etc/locale.gen`

Comment: You appear to have used the `ls` command, not `ln`.  The 'workaround' you provided will simply list two files, one in /usr/share and one in /etc.  Suggest you change your 'ls' to 'ln' and try again, creating a link to the correct file (/etc/localtime)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the timezone you are using exists?

The available timezones can be checked using `ls /usr/share/zoneinfo/*/*`